# anchor tag target iframe not working and link opening in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

On click of the link, the link is opening on a new tab on the browser and not in `iframe` and `iframe` is a blank box

```html
<iframe name="iframenew" height="300px" width="100%" title="Iframe Example"></iframe>
<p><a href="https://alight.com" target="iframenew">AVA</a></p>
```

I want the link to open in the `iframe` itself

Comment: That code should work fine.

Comment: work fine I tried in firefox

Comment: Curious if my answer solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Are you refers to the message `alight.com refused to connect.`?

Some websites disable embedding `iframe`, you could check using `X-Frame-Options`

> When attempting to embed an iFrame into your course, you may occasionally run into some errors such as seeing a blank white box or error notification. This is because not all websites can be embedded.

```html
<iframe name="iframenew" height="300px" width="100%" title="Iframe Example"></iframe>
<p><a href="https://alight.com" target="iframenew">AVA</a></p>
```

There is nothing wrong with the code, you could see below, I switch the link to Wikipedia main page, it will work find.

```html
<iframe name="iframenew" height="300px" width="100%" title="Iframe Example"></iframe>
<p><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" target="iframenew">AVA</a></p>
```